# Calling functions inside a vb.net-comvisible dll from c++

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have written a dll in vb.net (vs 2012) with classes and functions made comvisible. Like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<ComClass(InterFc.ClassId, InterFc.InterfaceId, InterFc.EventsId)> _
Public Class InterFc

  Public Const ClassId As String = "553CCD79-3067-44DE-B1AD-36A153F5C965"
  Public Const InterfaceId As String = "8C15295C-477B-434F-9FDC-4626D418DA9E"
  Public Const EventsId As String = "C434DF40-3F7B-45EE-B0D8-C85ABED03E88"

'(...)'

  Public Function TestFkt(ByVal intValue As Integer) As Integer

    TestFkt = 5 * intValue

  End Function

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
  End Sub

'(...)

End Class
```

First I'm wondering why the function-list in depency walker is empty, but that's not the problem.

Calling functions from VBScript works fine, like this:

```
Dim objCom
Dim iCounter

set objCom = CreateObject("VBNetDLL.InterFc")

For iCounter = 1 To 20
  MsgBox objCom.TestFkt(iCounter * 7)
Next
```

Also calling functions from VisualBasic (VB6) works fine:

```
Dim objCom

Set objCom = CreateObject("VBNetDLL.InterFc")

Msgbox objCom.TestFkt(3 * 7)
```

(Allright, code looks the same, but believe me, one is VBScript, the other Visual Basic ;-) )

What I can't get to work for the life of me, is calling those same functions from C++ (VS 2012). I have tried a lot of things, all starting with

```
#import <VBNetDLL.tlb>
using namespace VBNetDLL;
```

First thing is strange that Intellisense shows VBNetDLL::InterFC as "struct", not as a class.
Among the things I tried was:

```
InterFc *objControl = new InterFc;
```

which gave me "no appropriate default constructor available" and  "incomplete type is not allowed", and:

```
CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
CLSID clsid; 
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"InterFc", &clsid);

InterFc *pWApp;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IUnknown, (void **)&pWApp);
```

which compiled fine, but trying "pWApp->TestFkt" tells me "use of undefined type 'VBNetDLL::InterFc'", "left of '->TestFkt' must point to class/struct/union/generic type" and "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed".

Long story short: How do I call those memberfunctions from C++, especially since it seems so easy to use them from VBScript and VisualBasic6?

Comment: Your VBA/VB6 example code uses late-binding, you never name the type of the class.  Notable too is that auto-completion doesn't work in the VB6 editor.  But you try to use early-binding in your C++ code.  *Somebody* has to declare `InterFc`.  That somebody needs to be the [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx).  Beware the learning curve, don't assume you can just try it.  You have to read the docs to get it right.

Comment: Hello Hans, thanks for your answer. Well, the things I tried were methods I learned from this forum, among others, but unfortunately didn't do the trick. Thanks for mentioning early and late binding, I will look into that. Care to point me into some direction concerning docs to read? - Oh, sorry, I just saw that you have a link in your answer, thanks for that, too.

Comment: Hello and sorry, I still don't get it. I read the #import-doc, and had a look into the generated .tlh and .tli files, but didn't see anything that shows me (emphasize on "me" ;-) ) how I could get this right. Do I have to change the class definition in the original DLL? Have some parameters with the #import (though I don't see which)?

Answer (score -1):

Alright, for those who might stumble upon the same question, here is how I got this to work finally:

```
  CoInitialize(NULL); 

  _InterFcPtr pInterFC(__uuidof(InterFc));

  int iTestResult = (int)pInterFC->TestFkt(2);
```

Wouldn't it have been easier to just plain tell me instead of "Read the F** Manual!". Well, maybe not easier, but nicer, but it seems to be more important to be smart(er than others) than nice.

Thanks anyway.